# Activity indicator in status bar continues after app download is complete

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

Why does the activity indicator in the top left corner in the status bar continue to turn after the app download is complete? (iPad 2)

Answer (score 1):

Some apps will continue the download verification and the unpacking and Installation process after the download shows to be done, leading to the wheel continuing to spin till the process is completed.